# How to add a new custom resource to routes Rails 3

Tags: ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I add a custom route for a new resource in the Rails 3 routes?

I know how to do it for collections and members but this style doesn't seem to be working for new resources. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

So these work:

```
collection do
  get :wish
end

member do
  get :wish
end
```

But this doesn't work:

```
new do
  get :wish
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
resources :<resource name> do
  member do
    get '<custom action>'
  end
end
```

As an example lets see you have a controller called 'main' and if you have a custom action 'dashbord'

```
resources :admin do
  member do
    get 'dashbord'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In other words you want to match to something like:

`example.com/foos/new/custom` rather than `example.com/foos/1/custom/` or `example.com/foos/custom`

That's not RESTful, which just means there isn't an automatic route for it. You should be able to do it using non-resourceful routing, ie something like this should work:

`match 'resource/new/custom'=>'resource#custom'`

... where 'custom' is the action name in your controller.

See [the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) for more options and details.