# Rails - Best way / how to create Date-based Nav

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm new to rails and am working on extending the functionality of my basic blog app.  What I would like to do is create date-based navigation links. For example, I would like to have a list of links with the names of the months (as the links) and when you click on the month it shows you all the articles published in that month.

I'm struggling with how to best accomplish this.

Should I create a new Model / View / Controller for something like an ArticleArchive?  Or is the solution more simple based on my needs?

I've searched the other posts in the community and none seemed to answer this.  Any help with how to structure this and possibly implement is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example on approaching this, although in this I wanted to sort it by day.  This is for your controller action:

```
def index
  @article_days = Article.all.group_by{ |r| r.published_at }
end
```

To modify this to months, you'd want to do something like `r.published_at.beginning_of_month` in the example above and essentially `group_by` the name of the month.

In the view template:

```
<% @article_days.sort.each do |pub, articles| %>
  <h3><%= pub.strftime('%e %A, %B %Y') %></h3>
  <% for article in articles %>
    <%= article.title %><br/>
    <%= article.summary %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

There's a [screencast on this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month) as well.

**UPDATE**

OK - so you only want the names of the month appearing.  Keep the instance variable we setup in your index action along with your other code (you probably have setup `@articles = Article.all`).  Then where you want the links listed do:

```
<% @article_months.sort.each do |pub, articles| %>
  <h3><%= pub.strftime('%B') %></h3>
  <% for article in articles %>
    <%= link_to "#{article.title}", article_path(article) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike - This looks like it's getting there, but not quite what I'm getting at. I'd still like to have my regular index page list all of my articles as normal on the Articles#index page.  Somewhere else on the index page, I'd like to list the months (as clickable links) in which the respective articles were created (ex: "September").  Then clicking on "September" would take me to a page showing all articles that were created during September.

Comment: That'll be a bit more tricky - you'll need some logic to essentially do a similar iteration as above and save all the month names into an instance var, preferably as a hash.  If Articles is a resource you should setup a collection and have each month-link pointing at the collection route.  You'd need to access the instance var there and then process all the articles belonging to that month.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to setup Month ---> MonthArticle <--- Article relations, where the MonthArticle is a join table between this many-to-many relationship.  You *could* implement adding a record to the join table on a after_save callback in the Article model - this still feels crude to me though.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mike - with a little more help from these other stack posts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080547/ruby-on-rails-grouping-blog-posts-by-month, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920855/how-to-add-a-new-custom-resource-to-routes-rails-3) I was able to figure it out.